# Show that there are infinitely many positive integers that are not the sum of $15$ fourth powers

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

**The Question:**

Show that there are infinitely many positive integers that are not the sum of $15$ fourth powers.

---

**My Attempt:**

I am completely stuck.

The previous parts of this question were to show that there are infinitely many positive integers that are not the sum of:

(i) $3$ squares

(ii) $8$ sixth powers

(iii) $11$ tenth powers

For example, I did (i) by showing that all squares are congruent to either $0$, $1$, or $4 \pmod 8$ and hence all numbers of the form $7+8k$ cannot be the sum of three squares.

Similarly, I found $9+27k$ for (ii) and $12+50k$ for (iii) through exhaustive trial and error.

However, I couldn't do $15$ fourth powers, even with the help of a computer efficiently computing all the modulos for me.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Look at [Waring's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem) in Wikipedia.

Comment: I already did, but I have yet to find anything that I could use in there?

Answer (score 3):

Try
$$     31 \cdot 16^n    $$

It begins with the observation that $x^4 \equiv 0, 1 \pmod {16}$ but there is more to be done

For $31 \cdot 16^n$ with $n \geq 1,$ if any of the fourth powers are odd, there are at least sixteen odd fourth powers. On the other hand, if we have all even numbers, then dividing each by $2$ gives a representation of $31 \cdot 16^{n-1},$ so induction says sixteen are required

Comment: But why the $31$?

Comment: I tried $31 \cdot 16=496$ and it doesn't work?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am not sure I exactly follow your argument. Would you mind to elaborate a bit please?

Comment: @glowstonetrees For the inductive step, suppose for a contradiction that $31 \cdot 16^n = \sum_{i \in I} {x_i}^4$ for $|I| \leq 15$. By considering the remainders mod 16, if you have one odd power $\equiv 1$ you will need (at least) 15 more odd powers to make $31 \cdot 16^n \equiv 0$ yet $|I| < 16$, so all powers must be even. But only fourth powers of even numbers are even, so we can write $x_i = 2 y_i$ for every $i \in I$ and obtain $31 \cdot 16^n = 16 \sum_{i \in I} {y_i}^4$. So $31 \cdot 16^{n-1}$ can be written as a sum of the $|I| \leq 15$ fourth powers ${y_i}^4$, contradicting the I.H.